# Why i didn't get Logout Button in Next Activity in Facebook Integration with sdk 4.0.1

Tags: android, facebook-login

I Login Successfully with Facebook Sdk 4.0.1 and goto second activity which is logout activity i click on logout button and redirected again to Main activity but actually i got there again Logout button which is my Login button which change to Logout by Facebook Sdk. So please tell me what's wrong with me. 
Please tell me how i get that Logout Button in my Next Activity

```js
public class  MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    LoginButton loginButton;
    FacebookSdk mFacebook;
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"public_profile", "user_photos", "read_stream", "email" };
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String userName, emailId, userFacebookId, userId;
    URL image_value;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("Inside onCreate  ");
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
        // If using in a fragment
//        loginButton.setFragment();

        // Callback registration
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("accessToken", loginResult.getAccessToken().toString());
                        editor.apply();

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                                try {
                                    System.out.println("Inside onSuccess  ");

                                    userFacebookId = graphResponse.getJSONObject().getString("id");
                                    userName = graphResponse.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                                    emailId = graphResponse.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                                    userId = graphResponse.getJSONObject().getString("link");

                                    try {
                                        image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userFacebookId + "/picture?type=large");
                                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString("userFacebookId", userFacebookId);
                                    editor.putString("userName", userName);
                                    editor.putString("emailId", emailId);
                                    editor.putString("userId", userId);
                                    editor.putString("image_value", image_value.toString());
                                    editor.apply();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, logOut.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        System.out.println("Inside onCancel  ");
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                        System.out.println("Inside Error  " + exception);
                        // App code
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("Inside onActivityResult  "+resultCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second activity logout method,use following line to ask the `LoginManager` to logout as

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

So it will show "Login" text on facebook login button in your Main activity.

Comment: Thanx @Giru Bhai  you save my whole day.

Comment: @UlhasPatil Happy to help,now enjoy your day :)